# What is the relationship between internal page cache and dynamic page cache?

Tags: caching, 9

I faced a problem in my browser. Firstly, I removed an internal cached page that could be accessed by anonymous authenticated users. The page was still cached from the dynamic page cache.

I accessed the page by reloading the web browser that cached the page; the browser displayed the cached page, and the page was cached from the internal page cache.
Then, I cleaned the internal page cache and the dynamic page cache.

I accessed the page by reloading it from the web browser that cached the page; the browser displayed the not-cached page, and the page wasn't cached from the internal page cache.

What is the relationship between internal page cache and dynamic page cache?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the internal page cache runs strictly for anonymous users and doesn't vary the content. So, for example, if the "About" page was cached, there would only be one copy of it, and all anonymous users would get that.

Dynamic page cache runs for all users (authenticated and anonymous) and also has the ability to vary the content in either case. So you would want to use this if you wanted to serve up personalized content (like based on session or IP address or whatever) for anonymous users. And you would probably want to disable the Internal page cache so it doesn't get in the way. Otherwise, should be fine to keep them both enabled.